# Changing an array to list in TFS Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, arrays, list, mdx

Creating a report in Team Foundation Server(TFS) and my parameter is set as an array and I want to be able to display this array. I want to be able to switch the array to a list and then be able to show what is selected out of the list by the parameter the user selects. Can someone help please?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi-valued parameter is returned as an array, have you tried something like...

```
=JOIN(Parameters!MyParameter.Label,",")
```

...in a text box?

Comment: I did and that worked. I meant to write a comment stating the answer. Thank you though!